# Radio Receiver IC

Tags: rf, radio, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation

I am a Junior EE student that is interested in putting together a small radio receiver project for fun and to get some general practice with design. I have found these receiver chips from Silicon Labs [Si4732/34/35.](http://www.silabs.com/products/audio/fm-am-receiver/Pages/si473435.aspx) I would like to hook up the final design with a small LCD screen to show the frequency and then be able to listen with a standard pair of headphones through a 3.5mm headphone jack. My question is does anyone have experience with these chips or are there other chips out there that will better suit my needs? My second question is am I attempting to embark upon a project that is too ambitious for one person? Thank you for the help and advice. This is also my first post so if I have violated any rules around here please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with that series of wireless chips from Silicon Labs then you should check out their reference design kits which may be more suitable for getting started with development than simply ordering the standalone.

With design kits, you usually have options of adding LCD screens and other connectors much more easily and they usually come with some IDE for developing software right off the bat, and even some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think it is too ambitious when for a couple of dollars you can get a TEA 5767 board with all the functions necessary to actually put it to use.

[Single-station FM radio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/306497/single-station-fm-radio/306535#306535)

Instead of thinking about single chips, it is actually easier and less expensive to go with an entire FM radio with simple digital programming and no drift.  All on one circuit board, plus a Nano and a small amp, all of which fits on a very small speaker.

Follow that link to see how simple the program is, and how small the whole receiver can be.  This one is for a single frequency, but with the addition of two buttons you can have it scan up or down.  Plus, you can have your software set up with presets and you can step through them with one button.  Whatever you want.

Have fun!